# Form validation with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, validation, axios

I'm attempting to create a user registration form and running into a roadblock with displaying form validation errors.

**Problems:**
1) The input no longer posts (axios) to the db upon submission for inputs that don't have errors 2) The error message does not go away upon the error being fixed.

Side note: I've commented out the firstNameError, lastNameError, and emailError as to only focus on the passwordError.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Form, Container } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class RegisterUser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeFirstName = this.onChangeFirstName.bind(this);
    this.onChangeLastName = this.onChangeLastName.bind(this);
    this.onChangeEmail = this.onChangeEmail.bind(this);
    this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      firstNameError: '',
      lastNameError: '',
      emailError: '',
      passwordError: '',
    }
  }

  onChangeFirstName(e) {
    this.setState({
      firstName: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onChangeLastName(e) {
    this.setState({
      lastName: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onChangeEmail(e) {
    this.setState({
      email: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onChangePassword(e) {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value
    })
  }

  validate() {
    // let firstNameError= '';
    // let lastNameError= '';
    //  let emailError= '';
    let passwordError = '';

    if (!this.state.password.length < 6) {
      passwordError = 'Password must be at least 6 characters'
    }

    if (passwordError) {
      this.setState({ passwordError })
      return false
    }

    return true;
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const isValid = this.validate()
    if (isValid) {
      const user = {
        firstName: this.state.firstName,
        lastName: this.state.lastName,
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password,
      }

      console.log(user);

      axios.post('http://localhost:5001/users/add', user)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));

      this.setState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>First name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              id="firstName"
              required
              value={this.state.firstName}
              onChange={this.onChangeFirstName}
            />
            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>
              {this.state.firstNameError}
            </div>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>Last name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              id="lastName"
              type="text"
              required
              value={this.state.lastName}
              onChange={this.onChangeLastName}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>
            {this.state.lastNameError}
          </div>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="email"
              id="email"
              required
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.onChangeEmail}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>
            {this.state.emailError}
          </div>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="password"
              id="password"
              required
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.onChangePassword}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>
            {this.state.passwordError}
          </div>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Control
              type="submit"
              value="Register"
              className="btn btn-primary"
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not being reset by your code in validate. If the password is valid it should be reset with:

```
this.setState({ passwordError: '' })
```

I wrongly assumed `if(passwordError)` would return true for an empty string, but it does not. If you're able to debugg your code in the browser with developer tools you might be able to see why correct content does not get posted. It might be a result of using a constant for the valid flag.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. One piece was on the backend, but the other piece was in the code on original post, where I had an exclamation mark within the password validation error that should not have been there.

```
if (!this.state.password.length < 6) {
  passwordError = 'Password must be at least 6 characters'
}
```

Worked when I changed it to:

```
if (this.state.password.length < 6) {
  passwordError = 'Password must be at least 6 characters'
}
```